# what's the best way to add the state in a page title for seo

Tags: seo, title

For a page title, what's the best way to add the state to the page title for SEO purposes?

For example, should it be:

"Central Pennsylvania Shoe Repair"

or

"Central PA Shoe Repair"

or

"Central Pennsylvania PA Shoe Repair"

I want it to be searchable and discoverable but is the last too redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Google Adwords Tool to see what people are actually typing in. Also, Google is smart enough to know PA is the same as Pennsylvania so the difference won't be much regardless of which is more popular.

Comment: +1 ... and you'll probably find that people are more likely to type in the name of their city versus "central PA"

Answer (score 1):

John is correct on this. It really depends on keyword volumes and what you're targeting. I'd also add that you need to make sure that the URL and H1 of the page align with your title, e.g.,

***Pennsylvania Shoe Repair***

URL: `http://www.yoursite.com/pa-philadelphia/shoe-repair`

If you only focus on the title you won't be able to rank well.